# Should I edit a question or ask a new one?

Tags: support

I Want to know the difference between display managers and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58528/whats-the-difference-between-gdm-and-lightdm) question, but it does not include SDDM. Should I edit that question to include SDDM or ask as a separate one?

Comment: I see you asked your question, it is a good idea to link it here so people know http://askubuntu.com/questions/860924/what-are-the-current-display-managers-and-how-to-choose-the-correct-one-what-ar

Answer (score 8):

IMO you should ask a new question. That one is old and very specific.

You should write the question to include comparisons of ALL current display managers, then we would have a good and detailed up to date comparison.

Also, a lot has change, so the current answer is likely dated anyway.

As this would be a very useful question, I would be willing to give a bounty to anyone who wants to write a grate answer for us ;)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't do either. Big-list type questions aren't well-suited to the Stack Exchange format. They're a pain to keep updated. New entries don't get anywhere near as many views as older ones, so quality control on them is more difficult.

Also, other big list questions (like [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available)) have this notice on them:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but **it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site**, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. While you are encouraged to help maintain its answers, please understand that "big list" questions are not generally allowed on Ask Ubuntu and will be closed per the help center.

Also, the question that you asked is also soliciting opinions:

> Why should I choose one over others?

I'd VTC just for that, even if it wasn't too broad.

Comment: Thank you, then I will find it myself. Thank you

Comment: I simplified the question. now you can answer it.

Comment: @muru Although I agree with the big list argument. I don't agree about it being the case for this question.

Comment: @Dan it was the case for the question OP [actually posted at first](http://askubuntu.com/posts/860924/revisions): "I want to know what is a display manager and differences between them. Why should I choose one over others?" That's a classic big-list question.